# Price Break Down & Limits on Amulet of Mighty Fist?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, pricing

Alright so I somehow mad a goof up in my group playing pathfinder. I bought an Agile Amulet of Mighty Fist +1 for 4k. I had seen that price listing someplace but when shown the page for the item today it said "Alternatively" rather than "Additionally". So now I am trying to figure out how to price out upgrading/maximum limits on the item.

So a simple +1 to +5 Amulet of Mighty Fist is:
4,000 gp (+1)
16,000gp (+2)
36,000gp (+3)
64,000gp (+4)
100,000gp(+5)

So how do I price this WITH a weapon enhancement added? Such as Agile (+1 bonus)

Is it really 16,000 to have an Agile Amulet of Mighty Fist +1?

Would it really be 36,000 for an Agile Amulet of Mighty fist +2?

Am I limited to +5? So an Agile Amulet of Mighty Fist stops at +4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16,000 gp is the correct price.

*Agile* is +1-equivalent, that is, it costs the same as adding a +1 enhancement bonus. Since the *amulet* also already has a +1 enhancement bonus, adding another would result in a +2 bonus, so for the purposes of price, *+1 agile* is the same as *+2*, i.e. 16,000 gp.

And yes, it is limited to +5-equivalent, total:

> An amulet of mighty fists cannot have a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus special ability bonus equivalents) higher than +5.

Yes, the *amulet of mighty fists* is absurdly overpriced and limited.

Comment: Off the main question a bit any decent alternatives? I'd rather not wait till after level 10 to be able to do much in regards to improving unarmed strikes.

Comment: @NirvEND  If the GM allows *D&D 3.5* stuff, there's [this question.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64292/8610)