# Can Natural Weapons be Enhanced in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon

I'm trying to build a class in Pathfinder with the Bloodline Class Feature. I need to know, could I Enhance my claws with for EX: Flaming, even if they're natural weapons?

Comment: I made a small edit to remove the word [enchantment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Enchantment) and replace it with enhancement. It's common colloquial to use enchantment wrong, but because it's also an in-game term I like to keep them separated.

Answer (score 4):

## Only if they are masterwork

To create a magic weapon from a mundane one, the weapon must first be of masterwork quality.  Natural weapons generally are not of masterwork quality, and the quality of a weapon generally cannot be increased once the weapon is crafted.  That said, you may be able to craft new claws (or other natural weapons) with an appropriate crafting skill, or potentially purchase or start with masterwork ones, depending on your GMs campaign (q.v. [Can a monk's unarmed strikes be enchanted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/56986/14848)
, recalling that unarmed strikes are not natural weapons).

## An Amulet of Mighty Fists is the usual method

An [*Amulet of Mighty Fists*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists/) serves the same purpose for natural weapon users that purchasing magic armaments does for manufactured weapon users.  Unless you are monk trying to double dip, there's little reason to upgrade the weapons themselves individually rather than the *amulet* which provides the enchantment to *each* natural weapon you possess for the same cost.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Better?  It's still misleading re: *magic fang* et al, but I figure that's further off-topic.

Comment: I would put Amulet up top because I don't feel like *masterwork claws* come up very often (I've never seen and wouldn't allow a PC to "craft" natural weapons)

Answer (score 0):

## Yes.

Given that "Enhancement" is a pretty broad term covering all types of effects on natural weapons (claws in this instance) you may find some of these suitable.

### Feats

There is [Rending Claws](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rending-claws-combat/), [Eldritch Claws](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/eldritch-claws), [Throat Slicer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throat-slicer-combat), and [Feral Combat Training](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat) opens up a plethora of applicable feats.

### Spells

Requires PC to have the spell on your class spell list.
[Magic Fang (and Greater Magic Fang)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang), [Vine Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vine-strike), [Bloody Claws](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bloody-claws), [Angelic Aspect](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/angelic-aspect) (just gives aligned status).

### Psionics

Requires PC be psionic.
[Psionics Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-fist-psionic/) (and [Greater Psionic Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/greater-psionic-fist-psionic/)), [Aligned Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/aligned-attack-psionic/) (just gives aligned status), [Wounding Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/wounding-attack-psionic/), and [Unavoidable Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/unavoidable-strike-psionic/).

Answer (score -1):

I'm know I'm late but the  Shifter has a natural weapon that  Turns magical. And if I remember  Magical weapons count as masterwork. So I'm just spitballing but  I think you could enchant those.

Comment: Welcome to RPG stack exchange! Your answer would benefit from citations from the relevant sourcebook(s). Just thinking something, especially in a context where hard facts should be available, is not really sufficient.